# Collecting Data from Webview

Tags: android, webview

I just want to ask a simple question.

I have this html page that i downloaded (with its files) and placed it in the assets folder and loaded it in the webview, on submit the webpage sends the data filled in text field, my question is can I detect the onSubmit click, and if I can, can I retrieve the sent data so that I can save them in sqlite in case there's no internet and send them when the app is connected.

Regards,

Comment: an html page with the js function, a java class interface with js function listener attached with your web view and some java buttons to trigger that would help! lemme post an example for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you can do! HOPE THIS MAKES SENSE

consider in your asset folder you have an html file like

/assets/mypage.html

which has some js in it like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>
<p id="mytext">Hello!</p>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Open Dialog" onClick="openAndroidDialog()" />
<script language="javascript">
   function showAndroidToast(toast) {
       AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
   }

   function openAndroidDialog() {
       AndroidFunction.openAndroidDialog();
   }

   function callFromActivity(msg){
 document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = msg;
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and your xml design is like this for the app Activity of java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/msg"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
 android:id="@+id/sendmsg"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Msg to JavaScript"
   />
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

now in your MainActivity.java class I am using an interface inside of it for the listeners like this

```
    package com.rizwan.AndroidHTML;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidHTMLActivity extends Activity {

 WebView myBrowser;
 EditText edtTxtMsg;
 Button btnSendMsg;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

       final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
        = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
       myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");

       myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
       myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

       edtTxtMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    btnSendMsg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendmsg);
    btnSendMsg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String msgToSend = edtTxtMsg.getText().toString();
    myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\""+msgToSend+"\")");

   }});

   }

 public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
  Context mContext;

     MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

     public void showToast(String toast){
         Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     public void openAndroidDialog(){
      AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
      = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidHTMLActivity.this);
      myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
      myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
      myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
      myDialog.show();
     }

 }
}
```